# Is boost::posix_time::ptime fixed size?

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

Is boost::posix_time::ptime fixed size?

I want to use it to replace some custom time type garbage someone made, but the class it needs to go into is part of a preallocated memory pool and must be fixed size.

If so, where can I find the guarantee?

It is not stated in the documentation as far as I see. If I was to look at the header, it could take me a year just to keep drilling down to see what the year_type is alone.

Comment: Doesn't http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/date_time/details.html#date_time.buildinfo imply that it uses a 64 bit integer?

"By default the posix_time system uses a single 64 bit integer internally to provide a microsecond level resolution. As an alternative, a combination of a 64 bit integer and a 32 bit integer (96 bit resolution) can be used to provide nano-second level resolutions."

Comment: @pablo Looks good enough for me! thank you sir. Add as an answer if you would like the checky mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/date_time/details.html#date_time.buildinfo

> By default the posix_time system uses a single 64 bit integer internally to provide a microsecond level resolution. As an alternative, a combination of a 64 bit integer and a 32 bit integer (96 bit resolution) can be used to provide nano-second level resolutions.

So, you should be safe assuming a 64 bit integer, as long as you don't fiddle with build parameters.